# Speed Calculation in R

Tags: r, simulation

How to calculate speed of object from the dataset given that I have x and y position of the object at different frames. This is the code I am using.

```
for (i in 1:(nrow(accdata))) {
  if (row1$Object == row2$Object) {
    d <- integer()
    v <- integer()
    d <- c(sqrt((row1$midx - row2$midx) ^ 2 + (row1$midy - row2$midy) ^ 2))
    v <- d / framerate 
  }
}
```

I am getting a single value of distance and velocity. I should be getting a vector as dataset has many rows

Comment: Can you share a small sample of your data and the desired output

Comment: What is the problem with this code? It looks alright. If you're having problems with it, you need to tell us what those problems are! And share your data using `dput()`

Comment: Please see the edited version

Comment: At each iteration you're overwritting d and v ..., create them before hand and use your i as index maybe ?

Comment: If `framerate` is actually a rate rather than a time interval, then the distance should be multiplied by the frame rate rather than divided. But this is maths/physics rather than a coding issue.

Comment: Can you please give me the code for that @Tensibai

Comment: Something liek that, create the vector at the desired size before the loop to avoid growing it within the loop which is slowing down `v<-integer(nrow(accdata)); for (i in 1:nrow(accdata)) { v[i] <- 'code for the value' }`

Answer (score 1):

`(row1$midx - row2$midx) * framerate` and `(row1$midy - row2$midy) * framerate` give you x and y component of velocity vector (please check dimensionality of frame rate as frame rate usually in fps ~ 1 / s). Please see the code below to get the components for velocity and velocity itself for the circular motion:

```
# data simulation
# circular motion
frame_rate <- 60 # in fps
dt <- 1 / frame_rate # in secs
t <- seq(1, (10 * pi), dt)
x <- sin(t) # in meter
y <- cos(t) # in meters
accdata <- data.frame(midx = x, midy = y) # coordinates, in meters

# velocity calculations
dx <- c(NA, diff(accdata$midx))
dy <- c(NA, diff(accdata$midy))
vx <- dx / dt
vy <- dy / dt
v <- sqrt(vx ^ 2 + vy ^ 2)
res <- cbind(accdata, dx, dy, vx, vy, v)
head(res)
```

Output:

```
       midx      midy          dx          dy        vx         vy         v
1 0.8414710 0.5403023          NA          NA        NA         NA        NA
2 0.8503587 0.5262034 0.008887753 -0.01409891 0.5332652 -0.8459344 0.9999884
3 0.8590103 0.5119583 0.008651548 -0.01424507 0.5190929 -0.8547043 0.9999884
4 0.8674232 0.4975710 0.008412940 -0.01438728 0.5047764 -0.8632367 0.9999884
5 0.8755952 0.4830456 0.008171994 -0.01452549 0.4903197 -0.8715294 0.9999884
6 0.8835240 0.4683859 0.007928779 -0.01465967 0.4757267 -0.8795800 0.9999884
```